# onstat -g dis shows 2 servers incorrectly in informix server

Tags: database, informix

I have an informix server that i ve installed only one instance on it. but the command " onstat -g dis" results somthing like this and i dont know where these data are stored incorrectly.
thanks in advance...

[informix@XXX ~]$ onstat -g dis

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC2AEE -- On-Line -- Up 00:44:54 -- 136364580 Kbytes

There are 2 servers found

Server        : S1

Server Number : 24

Server Type   : IDS

Server Status : Up

Server Version: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC2AEE

Shared Memory : 0

INFORMIXDIR   : /data/informix

ONCONFIG      : /data/informix/etc/onconfig.S1

SQLHOSTS      : /data/informix/etc/sqlhosts

Host          : Host1

---

Server        : S2

Server Number : 23

Server Type   : IDS

Server Status : Down

Server Version: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 14.10.FC2AEE

Shared Memory : 0

INFORMIXDIR   : /data/informix

ONCONFIG      : /data/informix/etc/onconfig.S2

SQLHOSTS      : /data/informix/etc/sqlhosts

Host          : Host2

Comment: Umm... that output suggests that you have defined two instances: 'S1' and 'S2'. Check what you have in the /data/informix/etc directory (sqlhosts entries, onconfig files)

Answer (score 0):

A significant portion of the information used by `onstat -g dis` (server discovery) comes from the `/INFORMIXTMP` directory, which contains a number of 'hidden' files with names that start with a `.`.  In particular, the file `.infxdirs` identifies directories which have, at some time or another, been used as `$INFORMIXDIR` for a server.  The discovery process looks for those directories, and in particular for the `etc` subdirectory, and can then track information about the servers from files in there.  In particular, for a server `demoserver01`, it will look for the files `.conf.demoserver01` and `.infos.demoserver01`.  The presence of the `.infos` file indicates that the server is (probably) running; the `.conf` file indicates that the server exists, or once existed.

If you look in your `/INFORMIXTMP/.infxdirs` file, you'll find at least `/data/informix` listed.  If you look in `/data/informix/etc`, you should find both `.conf.S1` and `.conf.S2` files in there.  You will presumably only find `.infos.S1` since that it is the running server.